# What is the name of the data set used to calibrate FPR and FNR for a model?

Tags: terminology, calibration

In spam classification domain, we often train the models on different sets than the production. Then we are faced with the problem of calibrating the models with ROC curves to find a proper cut-off point, and then contemplate the FPR and FNR.

What is the name of the labelled random sample from production that is used for such calibration? Internally I call it a "calibration dataset", but I have doubts if this is the established name. Google turned out empty.

Comment: I would call it "wasted dataset" because FPR and FNR are poor measures and only apply when predictions and outcomes can take on only two distinct values.

Comment: @FrankHarrell I've updated the question. FPR/FNR is what I have to include in the final report, but obviously the journey starts with the ROC curve. We never consider other than two-level categorization. But that is beside the point, as we still would need a calibration dataset if we were dealing with multi-group categorization.

Comment: Not clear why the journey starts with the ROC curve.  It has the same transposed conditional problem as sensitivity and specificity.

Comment: @FrankHarrell, what do you mean by "transposed conditional problem"?

Comment: Sensitivity and specificity, which form coordinates on the ROC curve, are probabilities of predictors given outcomes.  We want probability of outcomes given predictor values.